# How to resolve the "cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects" in Python?

Tags: python, discord

I am making a basic Discord bot for my server which will respond according to specific words included in a message. I want to be able to add new bot response message to the replit database straight from Discord. But when I try to concatenate my default response message list(`starter_encouragements`) and the replit database (`db["encouragements"]`), its says I can't concatenate strings and lists. I'm pretty sure both of them are lists..

```
import discord 
import os
import requests
import json
import random
from replit import db

client = discord.Client()

sad_words = ["sad", "depressed", "unhappy", "mad", "anxious", "disappointed", "miserable", "depressing"]

starter_encouragements = [ "Cruel cruel world",
    "But you're still a lovely person/bot",
    "Just hold on tight.. Nothing lasts forever!",
  ]

def get_quote():
  res = requests.get("https://zenquotes.io/api/random")
  json_data = json.loads(res.text)
  quote = json_data [0]['q'] + " ~" + json_data [0]['a']
  return(quote)

def update_encg (encg_msg):
  if "encouragements" in db.keys():
    encouragements = db["encouragements"]
    encouragements.append(encg_msg)
    db["encouragements"] = encouragements
  else:
    db["encouragements"] = (encg_msg)

def delete_encg (index):
  encouragements = db["encouragements"]
  if len(encouragements) > index:
    del encouragements[index]
    db["encouragements"] = encouragements



@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('{0.user} is Online..'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):

  if message.author == client.user:
    return
  
  msg = message.content
  
  if msg.startswith('$inspire'):
    quote = get_quote()
    await message.channel.send(quote)

  options = starter_encouragements
  if "encouragements" in db.keys():
    options = options + db["encouragements"]

  if any(word in msg for word in sad_words):
    await message.channel.send(random.choice(options))

  if msg.startswith('$new'):
    encg_msg = msg.split("$new ",1) [1]
    update_encg(encg_msg)
    await message.channel.send("New message line added!")

  if msg.startswith('$del'):
    encouragements = []
    if "encouragements" in db.keys():
      index = int(msg.split("$del",1) [1])
      delete_encg(index)
      encouragements = db["encouragements"]
    await message.channel.send(encouragements)


client.run(os.getenv('key'))
```

The third line of this code fragment is where it says I cannot concatenate strings and lists:

```
        options = starter_encouragements
          if "encouragements" in db.keys():
           options = options + db["encouragements"]
```

Comment: try `options+[db["encouragements"] ]`

Comment: you can also use `options.append(db["encouragements"])`

Comment: Your assumption that you always have two lists is mistaken. Look at the `else` clause in your update function. Did you want to use square brackets? If that isn't the issue,  please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Mine isn't the perfect solution, but it could resolve you problem fast.
Instead of write `options = options + db["encouragements"]`, try to write `options = str(options) + str(db["encouragements"])` , and after this line of code write `print(options)`, as this:

```
options = starter_encouragements
  if "encouragements" in db.keys():
    options = str(options) + str(db["encouragements"])
    print(options)
```

Now try to run the script and watch what it will print in the terminal.
In the terminal you cold see which is the list, and you will be able to add the index to it to print the exact element you need from the list.

Comment: you can't convert a `list` into `str`. `options` is a list

Comment: @Ajay You can certainly call `str` on a list (even though it is a bad idea in this case).

Comment: I was thinking about "writing that" so I could see the terminal output and modify the code to get the right item from the list

Answer (score 0):

if you want the result as a string:

```
options = " ".join(options) + db["encouragements"]
```

if you want the result as a list:

```
options.append(db["encouragements"])
```

Comment: `await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 68, in on_message
    update_encg(encg_msg)
  File "main.py", line 27, in update_encg
    encouragements.append(encg_msg)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append' `

this is the error I got. I'm confused

Comment: yes it is a list and the datas in `db["encouragements"]` are strings.
Now how do I combine the two? Because I want to randomize the content of both

Comment: you have this error because encouragements is a string, so you have to do `encouragements = [encouragements]` and then `encouragements.append(encg_msg)`

Comment: I don't really know man.. doesn't work either

Comment: same traceback?

Comment: yeah.. I saw this tutorial from freecodecamp and they somehow manage to concatenate those. I run their exact source code but it doesn't work on mine either